# SQL IF statement bug

Tags: mysql, sql

```
create view Com as
select C.id,
IF(A.agree = null) THEN
0
else A.agree
end if
+
IF(GA.agree = null) THEN
0
else GA.agree
end if
FROM
comments C left join AGREES A on A.id_comment=C.id left join GAGREES GA on GA.id_comment=C.id
```

this code has a syntax error how can i fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
SELECT C.id,
       IFNULL(A.agree, 0) + IFNULL(GA.agre, 0)
FROM comments C 
    left join AGREES A on A.id_comment=C.id 
    left join GAGREES GA on GA.id_comment=C.id
```

Comment: I don't like coalesce because it has a weird name :)

Answer (score 5):

`= null` doesn't mean nothing. You have to use `is null`

Comment: @exculuber - just use `IS NULL` instead of `= NULL`.  `NULL` is an unknown value, so nothing can **EQUAL** it.

Comment: I don't undestand what you're trying to do. Please note that when you do a sum, if even one of the value is null, the sum is null. So you have to use coalesce. For example select 1+ null gives you null while select 1 + coalesce(null,0) gives you 1

Answer (score 2):

You can't nest an `if` block in a query like that. If you need to implement logic like that you'd use a `case` statement. However, in this *case* you'd simply use `coalesce()` or `isnull()` in-line.

```
select
 c.id
,isnull(a.agree,0) + isnull(ga.agree,0)
from Comments as c
left join Agrees as a
on a.id_comment = c.id 
left join GAgrees ga
on ga.id_comment = c.id
```

... alternatively (and what you'll need for MYSQL):

```
select
 c.id
,coalesce(a.agree,0) + coalesce(ga.agree,0)
from Comments as c
left join Agrees as a
on a.id_comment = c.id 
left join GAgrees ga
on ga.id_comment = c.id
```

Answer (score 0):

in MySQL use
[**ISNULL()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_isnull) or
[**IS NULL**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_is-null) or
[**IFNULL**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull)